# Creating page in Action Bar Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm very new to programming, and right now I'm trying to make an Android app. I've got quite a bit done, but now I'm trying to make a Downloads page in the Action Bar. I have the string in the Action Bar and everything in the main.xml. Heres my main.xml file:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/downloads"
 android:title="Downloads"
 android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

But when I click Downloads in the app, it doesn't do anything. So I need to know what to add in the Main Activity and where to put the downloads XML file. Thanks!

Comment: All you need to know about Menu in Android is on the [official developper site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you search for this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {

    case R.id.PLACE_ID_OF_YOUR_ITEM:
         //...

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This Listener fires an event when an Item in the action bar is clicked. 
Now just do what you want to do when your download-item is clicked.

Comment: I got that added in my main activity, and I added the id of my item, but it still won't open. I don't know if I need this, but in my res/layout folder I have a downloads.xml. Does that need to be there? I'm sorry if I'm asking a dumb question, but like I said, I'm very new to this. But thanks for your first reply! Got me headed in the right direction :)

Comment: I would say, first test if it really fires an event by using an Log.d("Event fired");  just where I set the //... - if this works you can go on and either create a new Acitivity which uses your download.xml as contentview or a fragment which inflates your download.xml  -  There are lot's of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Damn, it doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: you have used case R.id.downloads: Log.d("Event fired") ??

Comment: Yea I did. I ended up making a normal button on the homepage and got it working, so I will just use that for now and maybe come back to this when I have more experience. But thanks for all your help man!